# Adjust ASP button element font size

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, font-size

How can I implement a font-resize feature that also adjusts the text size of all ASP elements?

I'm part of a team that is working to implement an interactive course catalogue as a class project.  The typical user for the site will be > 50, and one common request from surveys an interviews was to have a user-adjustable test size increase/decrease of not only the on-screen text, but the buttons, lists and other elements.

Another requirement for this class: everything has to be implemented in ASP.NET & C# 4.0.

According to the documentation, the object FontUnit controls the size and type style of ASP elements.  We're going to be using a number of elements nested inside HTML divs, and would like some way for a single button click to implement a page-wide text size increase/decrease.

I tried

`btnTextSize.Font.Size= FontUnit.Larger;`

to test on a couple elements, but there was no change in size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/controlling-font-size-with-javascript/

It's javascript, but it may work for your needs.

Comment: Looks like that may work, but does ASP store its font sizes as pixels or ems?

Comment: Tried it, apparently `document.getElementsByTagName` doesn't work on gathering asp elements.